# Different favicon for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon, remote-desktop

When accessed through remote desktop in Internet Explorer 11, my site's favicon is very small and doesn't have any transparency. However, Chrome, through the same remote desktop session, handles transparency just fine.

[image: IE's favicon]

[image: Chrome's favicon]

My users will be using a mix of IE and Chrome, and it would be nice to have the icon look good in both.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the RDP config, which I've no control over, so a "good enough" solution would be to create an icon with IE's tab background gray. It'll match better than the black.

Comment: 1) this probably belongs better in superuser.com 2) you are not specifying the configuration of the local and remote computer. Different RDP versions + different servers result in different experiences: in some cases, the "Aero" theme is disabled, in some, the desktop experience pack is not installed (e.g.: Windows Server), in some cases if the latency is bad RDP will disable all these features. So, I suggest moving this to superuser.com and improving the setup of the systems.

Comment: I thought about posting on superuser.com and specifying the setup, but my question isn't how to change the setup; I don't have access to change anything there.

You're correct though. Aero's disabled, it's running Windows Server, and we're restricted to 16bit color depth.

Comment: That is probably the reason then - IE picks up the theme from the OS itself and apparently that theme can not handle transparency properly (the StackOverflow logo is transparent). Fix is probably to change the theme or get Aero working (see probably here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uspartner_ts2team/2010/03/09/aero-glass-on-remote-desktop-services/ ), I have not checked if either of these work though.